# Oracle regex to ignore slash

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, select

I try to create regex, which ignores slash-sign by selection.
For example i have content like this in my column "things":

```
arbit
t/obt 
t/comp 
t/dor
cramp
pod
```

I only can type: pod, tdor, arbit, tcomp

I have tried with "`REGEXP_SUBSTR`"-Expression, but maybe it is not appropriate for this issue.

Comment: what do you want as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you have the following table:

```
$ select * from PERSONS;

PersonID LastName FirstName ADDRESS CITY
1          arbit     null      null  null           
2          t/obt     null      null  null           
3          t/comp    null      null  null           
4          t/dor     null      null  null           
5          cramp     null      null  null           
6          pod       null      null  null
```

You can use the following simple `replace` that does not use regex:

```
select Replace(Lastname,'/','') from persons;
-- you can omit the replacement part select Replace(Lastname,'/') from persons;

--Replace(Lastname,'/','')--    
arbit
tobt
tcomp
tdor
cramp
pod
```

If you really need to do a complex search and replace that uses regex:
(this is not necessary in your case)

```
$ select REGEXP_REPLACE(Lastname, '/', '') from persons;

--REGEXP_REPLACE(Lastname, '/', '')--
arbit
tobt
tcomp
tdor
cramp
pod
```

You can also omit the replacement part since it is empty:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(Lastname, '/') from persons
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use simple replace to remove `/`:

```
SELECT things, REPLACE(things, '/', '')
FROM tab
```